# Error with join and CakePHP

Tags: mysql, cakephp, left-join

What am I doing wrong here?

```
        $sub_data = $this->Subscriber->find('all', array(
            'joins' => array(
                'table' => 'subtypes',
                'alias' => 'Subtype',
                'type' => 'LEFT',
                'conditions' => array(
                    'Subtype.id = Subscriber.plan',
                )
            ),
            'conditions' => array(
                'Subscriber.plan' => $plan['Subtype']['id'],
                'Subscriber.authcode !=' => '',
                'Subscriber.subended' => '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
                'Subtype.authorize_trial_only' => '1',
            )
        ));
```

Somehow the final statement is not being generated correctly. That's that part where I get a SQL error:

> ... FROM `subscribers` AS `Subscriber`
>   subtypes Subtype LEFT **Array**  WHERE
>   `Subscriber`.`plan` = '10' AND
>   `Subscriber`.`authcode` != '' AND
>   `Subscriber`.`subended` = '0000-00-00
>   00:00:00' AND
>   `Subtype`.`authorize_trial_only` = '1'
>   AND ...

Comment: By the way, $plan['Subtype']['id'] is a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should it be

```
 'conditions' => array(
                'Subtype.id' => 'Subscriber.plan',
            )
```

Or am I just crazy?

EDIT:

Do you perhaps need to add another level of array() in there?  i.e.

```
'joins' => array( array ( 'table' => ...
```

Comment: I've tried that already. I was following the syntax here:

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1047/Joining-tables

Comment: Mm, yes, you do look like you've been quite careful with your syntax, which makes it strange.  Looks like the SQL is just concatenating all the stuff in your joins array instead of doing anything sensible with them.  Curiouser and curiouser...

Comment: See the controller class that's the first code example here: http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/nate/2009/01/21/quick-tip-doing-ad-hoc-joins-in-model-find... in that one, looks like there's an extra level of array nesting going on?

Comment: Thank you, that took care of it :)